# How to re-use a SQL query in a PL/SQL procedure?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

I am writing a PL/SQL procedure. In the body of this procedure, how can I use twice the same query without re-writing it ?

To simplify, let's say that I have this SQL query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
WHERE age > 18
```

Is there a way to "store it", so I could do for example :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO var1
FROM myQuery
```

I know the *WITH ... AS* keywords, but as I know it can be only used in the current statement, and I want to be able to call it from different statements.

Thanks !

Comment: You could make either `VIEW` or `STORED PROCEDURE` from the query, and call that.

Comment: Could you not create a procedure called "myProcedure" and then make multiple calls to that procedure within another procedure? E.g. Call "schema".myProcedure

Comment: @Siyual - +1 for VIEW.

Comment: a view would work, but if you used that approach for many cases like this you'd have an awful lot of highly specialized views which seems inappropriate to me

Comment: @DaveCosta +1, I am looking for a temporary way to store it, not like a view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various possibilities.  Here are the ones I think of immediately, there are probably others:

- Declare an explicit CURSOR using your query, and use that cursor multiple times in the body of your procedure.
- Store the query in a string variable, and use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to run it multiple times
- Execute the query once, storing the results in a local collection (nested table, most likely), and process those stored results multiple times
- Create a function that executes the query and returns its results as a nested-table type. Then `SELECT FROM TABLE( my_function )` multiple times

Comment: Thank you, the function is the closest to my need ! Cheers